# RecyclerView onCreateViewHolder() Performance

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

RecyclerView uses onCreateViewHolder() to inflate views when required.

If I pass in already inflated view to the  onCreateViewHolder() ..Does it improve the performance (reduces recyclerview loading time) ?
For example:-

```
 override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, type: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
     
       //instead of inflating views on the fly I am using ViewPool that I have created earlier
       
       val holder = MyViewHolder(MyViewPool.getAlreadyInflatedView())
       return holder
}
```

Has anyone tried this ?

onBindViewHolder() is empty (not doing anything there).

PS: I have not got any performance gain with this approach. I just wanted to know why

Comment: Recyclerview already implements reuseable viewpool under the hood, what you're trying to do is pointless

Comment: From https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LqBlYJTfLP4 : `onCreate` means _create_; the adapter won't ask you to create a view unless it needs you to.

Comment: I thought I could save the layout inflation time with this approach by using already inflated views. I referred this article from "Yelp"

https://engineeringblog.yelp.com/2018/05/android-search-perf-improvements-part-2.html

Comment: This looks like someone reinventing the wheel, there's no mention of RecyclerView which already handles most of that logic including pre-loading during scroll etc. by itself.

Comment: I could see this helping if your own thread pool is using AsyncLayoutInflater and starts seeding itself with views before the RecyclerView receives its data. Never tried it myself. You're only going to see  your initial data appear ever so slightly sooner though. Once you start scrolling, it's no longer going to be calling `onCreateViewHolder()` because it will be reusing the views already created.

Comment: @Tenfour04  Right, this is the intention. 
As of now 4 cards are drawn on screen taking 160ms (40*4) .I thought If I pre-inflate these views then I can speed-up the initial rendering of Recycler view.
But I could'nt see any performance gain. 
Now, onCreateViewHolder() function completes in ~1ms but still RecyclerView takes 160ms to render.

Comment: Maybe the bulk of the time is spent laying out the text and measuring all the views in the layout.